# Returns one getElementById but not the other

Tags: javascript

New to this, so please bear with me. I can make this work in jsfiddle (link below), but on my website it only returns the first getElementById, not the second. I've swapped them around to test.

Html:

```
<p id="spanDate"></p>
<p id="spanYear"></p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
    'August','September','October','November','December'];       
    var currentTime = new Date();
    y = currentTime.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = months[currentTime.getMonth() - 1] + " " + y;
    document.getElementById("spanYear").innerHTML = y;
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7039/

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a console error on your website?

Comment: What are you expecting the demo (fiddle) to do differently?

Comment: it's very likely that you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: check the browser's developer tools for any errors

Comment: try "var y=" instead of "y="? not sure if your code has different scope...

Comment: is the intent that the current month and year are filled into those elements, because the fiddle seems to do just that...? If this is not working in your actual code I would say it has something to do with the rest of the code on the page (that which is not included in the fiddle). My first guess would be that you have multiple elements on the page with that ID?

Comment: To clarify (for those wondering above)... the jsfiddle works as intended. My website has the issue (i.e. only returns whichever getElementById comes first. I've swapped them around within the code and again, whichever comes first works (not the second instance of getElementById). You will note I've created very unique IDs (i.e. 'spanDate' and 'spanYear', so there is definitely no duplication issues).

Comment: Why would someone mark down this post (-1)? I've been very clear, provided a jsfiddle and code. What more could I do? /sigh

Comment: I'll troubleshoot the recommendations above and respond in due course. Thank you to those that have provided assistance.

Comment: Resolved - but the only way I could get this to work was to separate the two getElementById and put them in different JS files.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - but the only way I could get this to work was to separate the two getElementById and put them in different JS files.